# How to get data related to Winter Bash?

Tags: support, api, winterbash

I was thinking of creating a nice question on [Programming Puzzles & Code Golf](https://codegolf.stackexchange.com/) related to [Winter Bash 2014](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/), but I need some specific data for that question - The number of hats of each user.

Is there a way to query the number of hats owned by a user using the stack exchange API?

Answer (score 8):

## The unofficial Winterbash inbox API

If you have any user's `account_id` then the hats information is just one call away.

And the call is

```
http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/api/inbox?accountId=<account_id>
```

For example, hats information about me can be retrieved via

http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/api/inbox?accountId=4996787

But here are the caveats:

- This is most probably a temporary API, so no idea how long it will work, or if it will change in between.
- <s>I have no idea whether it works with an API key or not, thus for now, it only works for yourself</s> It works for everyone who is participating in the WinterBash.

---

To get any user's `account_id`, simply use the `/users` API.

For example, a sample API for PPCG with name search on `peter` is

```
http://api.stackexchange.com/2.2/users?order=desc&sort=reputation&inname=peter&site=codegolf&filter=!)RwcIFaJnzoLPrdy_GOamMlj
```

which gives the following output

```
{
  "items": [
    {
      "account_id": 278703,
      "user_id": 194,
      "display_name": "Peter Taylor"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 262054,
      "user_id": 788,
      "display_name": "Peter Olson"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 4989165,
      "user_id": 31378,
      "display_name": "Peter Weistroffer"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 24885,
      "user_id": 8977,
      "display_name": "Peter Mortensen"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 23121,
      "user_id": 1852,
      "display_name": "Peter Lawrey"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 45792,
      "user_id": 833,
      "display_name": "PetersenDidIt"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 4284,
      "user_id": 842,
      "display_name": "peter"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 25835,
      "user_id": 1280,
      "display_name": "Peter Mourfield"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 3012,
      "user_id": 1441,
      "display_name": "Peter Hart"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 62463,
      "user_id": 1535,
      "display_name": "Peter Jaric"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 190859,
      "user_id": 1986,
      "display_name": "Peter DeWeese"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 15021,
      "user_id": 2019,
      "display_name": "peterchen"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 113435,
      "user_id": 2259,
      "display_name": "Peter Milley"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 130125,
      "user_id": 2648,
      "display_name": "Peter Smith"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 951403,
      "user_id": 3203,
      "display_name": "Peter John Acklam"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 130009,
      "user_id": 4617,
      "display_name": "Peter"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 13104,
      "user_id": 4648,
      "display_name": "Tony Peterson"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 8490,
      "user_id": 4871,
      "display_name": "Peter"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 31204,
      "user_id": 5419,
      "display_name": "Peter Smit"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 872850,
      "user_id": 6893,
      "display_name": "peter"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 349151,
      "user_id": 7927,
      "display_name": "Peter Majeed"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 25721,
      "user_id": 9002,
      "display_name": "Peter Gibson"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 211922,
      "user_id": 9036,
      "display_name": "Eric Peterson"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 104670,
      "user_id": 12672,
      "display_name": "PeterT"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 14690,
      "user_id": 12910,
      "display_name": "Peter Hosey"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 172638,
      "user_id": 13568,
      "display_name": "Peter Nixey"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 2799,
      "user_id": 13621,
      "display_name": "Peter Cooper"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 1988549,
      "user_id": 14149,
      "display_name": "Peter Horvath"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 2239333,
      "user_id": 14160,
      "display_name": "Peter Vasilev"
    },
    {
      "account_id": 1055603,
      "user_id": 14216,
      "display_name": "Peter W."
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: What makes you think this only works for yourself?  Using [your link](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/api/inbox?accountId=4996787), I can see your 19 hats, earned 34 times, just fine.  [This user currently only has 2 hats](http://stackapps.com/users/29477/aaditi-jain#winter-bash), which [you and I can both see without needing an API key](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/api/inbox?accountId=2840615).

Comment: @BrockAdams Weird, I tried for the first user in that above JSON. Peter Taylor. But it is giving [empty json](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/api/inbox?accountId=278703).

Comment: [Peter Taylor is apparently not participating in Winterbash](http://codegolf.stackexchange.com/users/194/peter-taylor) (or has no hats).  When you check users who do have hats, it works fine.

Answer (score 5):

http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/api/user-hats?userId=29538&host=stackapps.com

This returns an array of arrays. Each inner array contains three integers:

- The Id of the hat
- The number of times the user has earned this hat, all over the network
- 1 if the user has earned this hat on this particular site (Stack Apps, in this example); 0 otherwise.

Comment: Cool. When did API come into existence ?

Comment: Two years ago (except that it contained less data because hats were more strictly per-site). It's the API that gets called to populate the hat rack when you click on the "X hats" number on a user profile.

Comment: This is a good start, but how do we get a list of badge names to go with the ID's?  And, it looks like we can tease the hat images out of [the winterbash2014 page](http://winterbash2014.stackexchange.com/), but is there an easier way via the API?